# Tag aware sharding in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have been reading about tag aware sharding..These are the links I referred:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tag+Aware+Sharding
http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/
Kristina has explained the concept in a very lucid manner and one thing is for sure: this  enhancement is going to make MongoDB more developer-friendly.
But my question is.. It looks like tagging/retagging is meant to easily migrate chunks around..get all writes on to a preferred data center etc..But how does this fit into the old system of range partitioning and the way Mongo learns key-distributions for balancing? It is said that the shard-key cannot be changed, and that's because the data is assumed to be distributed across shards and changing the shard-key would disturb this. Isn't applying a tag essentially doing the same? So is tag-aware sharding *meant* to handle this problem?
**EDIT:**
And any idea how are the indexes affected by such huge migrations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aafreen,

You are correct. At this stage shard-tagging performs many of the same functions as balancing with the shard key. The one thing it does not do is perform any level of distribution beyond that of tagging. So it is probably more correct to say that the tagging architecture lives on top of the  existing sharding architecture.

You must keep in mind that tagging only governs:

a) where tagged data will go, untagged data will use the shard-key

b) that tagged data shared amongst a number of tagged servers will still need to be distributed

You can most certainly use the tag aware sharding to manually control data distribution in the same manner that the balancer does now, by making granular enough tags so that data is put where you want it and distributed evenly.

The use case however, is more like the Documentation you linked. Where you have a large number of shards broken up into a smaller subset. In this example you would be tagging each object and then the tag would push it to the correct geographic location (for lower latency retrieval) and once within the correct geography the original sharding architecture would take over and distribute amongst the tagged shards.

As for indexes, they are heavily affected by migrations, as they need to be repointed. But the level of load is the same for that of a large number of chunk migrations - like adding a new shard to a cluster.